# How to add specific elements to an existing tumblr theme?

Tags: html, css, grid, themes, tumblr

I am currently using a premade theme on my Tumblr (pixiplum.tumblr.com). I want to keep the overall design and sidebar/navigation for my downloads page, but want the posts to appear in a **grid-style** like this (https://kumikya.tumblr.com/dir) with filters.

I am confused as how to make this possible. I created the downloads page and used 'Standard Layout' and tried adding fitting codes to make the grid, but I am clueless. I also tried using the theme HTML as the custom HtML but this makes the page look weird, lol.

I am pretty clueless and hope to get a little more knowledge.
Thanks already :)
'

Comment: Hi. What have you tried with the HTML? If you've been editing the theme - past your code into your question so people can see it. If you don't think you know enough HTML you may be better off looking for another theme that already has the grid layout you want.

Comment: It looks not disimilar to Narnia theme https://wolfiestein.tumblr.com/narniatheme, these themes seem to use it https://www.google.com/search?q=NARNIA+BY+BLINK+AND+ITS+OVER+v.1.2.1+DISTRIBUTED+BY+THEME+CLOUD&oq=NARNIA+BY+BLINK+AND+ITS+OVER+v.1.2.1+DISTRIBUTED+BY+THEME+CLOUD&aqs=chrome..69i57.1222j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 
But you can modify the column width and it's also responsive. I would start with that.